# Как правильно разобрать строку?

Tags: c#, split

Получаю строку: **Иван** **5** рублей **20** копеек.
(значение выделенное **жирным** всегда разное)
Как разбить это всё в 3 переменные: name = Иван; rub = 5 рублей; kop = 20 копеек.

Comment: есть ли разделитель между значениями?

Comment: `Split`, цикл, условия, плюс ф-ция `int.TryParse`. Аккуратно собрать всё вместе. Можно без цикла несколькими `if`.

Comment: Bald, только пробел. иногда встречается и полное имя - Петров Иван Иванович

Comment: nick_n_a, можете пример привести, а то немного непонятно

Comment: Приведите ваш кусок кода, и что вам не понятно. Ф-ция `int.TryParse` отделяет числа от слов. По-моему такое задание нужно делать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если структура всегда одинакова, то можно зайти с конца, так будет проще всего.

```
String str = "Мне все равно как этого парня зовут 1 рубль 1 копейка";

String[] split = str.Split(' ');
Int32 splitCount = split.Count();

string kop = String.Join(" ", split.Skip(splitCount - 2)); 
string rub = String.Join(" ", split.Skip(splitCount - 4).Take(2));
string name = String.Join(" ", split.Take(splitCount - 4));
```

Comment: Ваш метод работает, только иногда встречается 12-23,26,28 копеек((

Comment: Всё, сам разобрался. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать регулярку. Например такую:

```
(?'name'.*?) (?'rub'\d+ рублей) (?'kop'\d+ копеек)
```

[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/ByjBxP/2)

Comment: а если будет 1 рубль?

Comment: то добавит в регулярку или `|`

Comment: в вопросе указано, что изменяемые значения выделены жирным. Слово "рублей" жирным не выделено, соответственно логично предположить, что оно неизменяемо. Если же это не так, то модифицировать её довольно просто, добавив через `|`  литерал "рубль" как выше советует @nick_n_a

Comment: @DreamChild а то что имя может меняться вас не смутило?

Comment: @tCode так а в чем проблема? В регулярке же в группе 'name' не задано конкретное имя Иван. Там  может быть в сущности что угодно, в том числе полное имя, содержащее  пробелы

Comment: это ладно написано что все что выделено жирным будет меняться, то есть для вас "2 рублей" и "1 рублей" - это ок?

Comment: Да ладно вам `(?'rub'\d+ (рублей)|(рубль))` или `(?'rub'\d+ рубл\w+)`

Comment: @tCode А это не ко мне вопрос "ок или не ок". Это к топикстартеру. Разве где-то в задаче сказано про морфологию? Вы слишком переусложняете. В этом случае вам потребуется писать парсер, учитывающий правила согласования числительных и существительных в русском языке. В крайнем случае можно литералы "рублей" и "копеек" заменить на группы любых символов

Answer (score -2):

```
string[] s = String.Split(' ');

name = s[0]; rub = s[1] + " " + s[2]; kop = s[3] + " " + s[4];
```